# Azure User Admin right to delete guest users

Tags: azure, external, roles

I have User Admin role assigned and just noticed that am not able to delete external users.
the user admin has right: microsoft.directory/users/delete and i guess that is not enough.
the global admin has right: microsoft.directory/users/allProperties/allTasks

Create and delete users, and read and update all properties.

Do you know if there is any other role that grants the right to delete external users? or am i missing here something?

Answer (score 0):

```
I have User Admin role assigned and just noticed that am not able to delete external users.
```

[image]

You can check [user admin roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#user-administrator) here.  As per document as shown in below image for this User admin role Delete or Restore users is not applicable.
[image]

As per your requirement Global Administrator has this delete user access privilege. Here you can go through [Global Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#global-administrator) rights.
[image]

```
there is any other role that grants the right to delete external users?
```

- AFAIK the **Global Administrator role is the only built-in role** in Azure AD that grants the ability ****to delete external users** but If you do not want to assign the Global Administrator role  but still you  want  to be able to delete external users, **you can create a custom role and assign the "microsoft.directory/users/delete" permission to it.**
- In Azure You can create custom role in different ways like
  ~Using Azure portal.
  ~Using PowerShell
  ~Using CLI
- To create custom role using portal **check your custom role is enabled or disabled as shown in below image Select your subscription or Resource group >> Access control >> +Add >> Add Custom role.**

[image]

- Creating Custom role is bit complicated if you are ok with custom role follow these detailed steps in [create custom role MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-portal) using Azure Portal.
- Create Custom role Using [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-powershell)